# Is there any way of changing a base image or a service and do not have to build the whole application again?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, development-environment, production-environment

I am new to docker and I have faced some complications understanding how big multi-level applications work with docker.

I want to use visual studio Asp .Net core and have several questions:

- If I make a trivial change to one service do I need to build the whole application and make a new image of it?
- How I am suppose to inform user of the change?
- Do I have to deploy the whole app again in case of a little change?
- If production images do not have access to source code how the developer is supposed to make change to production image?
- If my client is not willing to make a container of their database can I use a docker network to make a connection with that external SQL server?

Comment: _"Then I need to know that if production images do not have access to source code how the developer is supposed to make change to production image?"_

Sorry, I don't get your point. Can you explain your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. For that question, I recognized two types of images, one with the dev tag build by Visual Studio and one with default "latest" tag build by docker-compose command. For the production image I mean the latest tag image. It does not contain source code so I cannot edit its corresponding container.

Comment: You mean that the container only contains compiled code and how other developer can later change something?
_1._ For compiled code you have re-run the docker build for each compiled version. 
_2._ There is no way changing this compiled code. If other developer want to expand the container around the compiled code they can use your container in the `FROM` statement. If they have to change your source code the must have access to your source code and rebuild the image on their own each time.

Answer (score 0):

> If I make a trivial change to one service do I need to build the whole application and make a new image of it?
>
> Do I have to deploy the whole app again in case of a little change?

For each step in your Dockerfile Docker generates a intermediate container. If you use the same as before Docker use this cached intermediate container. If you change a command (e.g. add a package, copy new source code lines ...)  this step will be produce a new intermediate container. Every step after this run on the new intermediate container - so no cached can be used. 
So yes, you have to. But you can optimize your build using intermediate container and multi stage builds (see links).

> How I am suppose to inform user of the change?

At first: Use tags for versioning.This helps a lot. But how to inform is a problem of your use-case, not docker. It is the same as releasing a new "normal" software version. 
May you have a CI-Pipeline and can automatize this step. Or you have access to your customer systems and can automatically deploy the new container.

> if my client is not willing to make a container of their database can I use a docker network to make a connection with that external SQL server?

Docker Networks are for the (isolated) communication between Docker Containers. You can use the "normal" way to connect from a client to a external database. May you have to publish a port outside your container (see docker references). And be aware that the address `localhost` refers inside  a container, not your system.

This blog post are may helpful for you: 
[1] https://andrewlock.net/caching-docker-layers-on-serverless-build-hosts-with-multi-stage-builds---target,-and---cache-from/ 
[2]
https://www.busbud.com/blog/going-docker-multi-stage-builds/